# How can I disable a button on a worksheet?

Tags: excel, vba, button

I am trying to disable a button on a worksheet.

I could make it invisible but I'd rather have it on screen but not clickable and greyed out so it is obviously not clickable.

Here is my script for the button:

```
Sub LinkFile()
Call Module1.setup
Dim btn1 As Button
Dim t As Range

Set t = Range(Cells(3, "G"), Cells(4, "I"))

Set btn1 = ACImport.Buttons.Add(Left:=t.Left, Top:=t.Top, Width:=t.Width, Height:=t.Height)
btn1.Name = "Button1"
btn1.OnAction = "FileSearch"    ' MySub is executed when btn is clicked
btn1.Caption = "GO!"
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm afraid that Form buttons on the sheet do not have such an available property (Enabled) since Excel 2010. In fact, I mean this property exists, can be programmatically set but it does not change anything in the button behavior. **Try using ActiveX button instead** If you insist on using a Form button, a workaround can be the next:  Programmatically change the `Enalbled` property and put a preliminary check in the sub called by it. Something like that: `If Not ACImport.Shapes("Button1").Enabled Then Exit Sub`. The button will not be grayed out but it will do nothing if you make it `Disable`.

Comment: See also one of the answers [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/officeversion_other-customize/excel-2010-enabledisable-buttons-via-vba/793de6e3-6c20-4706-876d-1421209aad98). You could change the color index to 15 to grey it out but you can click the button anyway.

Comment: @Storax: I would say that they stated the same conclusion... To create an ActiveX button with an event it's a little more complicated, but possible. I did it in the past...

Comment: @FaneDuru: Yes, you are right but ActiveX buttons are also notorious to cause strange issues from time to time. On the other hand that `Enabled=False` does not have an effect for a form button is is also a strange issue.

Comment: @Storax: I did not face any strange issue using ActiveX buttons. But it is true, I used them very seldom. Only at somebody express request. But no complaints about them...

Comment: @FaneDuru: Unfortuantely it happens from time to time: [link1](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/cf82af5f-00f4-4620-9f3b-d6a320b33e44/bizarre-behavior-of-activex-controls-on-excel-worksheet?forum=isvvba), [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28638479/strange-activex-listbox-behavior-in-excel). Maybe it was not fair from me to use the word _notorious_

Answer (score 0):

For UserForms and ActiveX buttons, this will work:

`btn1.Enabled = False`

---

For the other worksheet button, you can try:

`btn1.ControlFormat.Ebabled = False`

or

`ACImport.Shapes("Button1").ControlFormat.Enabled = False`

---

If those do not work then you then you will have to make a judgement call.  You can switch to an ActiveX button.  Remove the button from the worksheet and place it on a UserForm.  Give up and let the button remain enabled.  Or creatively push boundaries by employing different strategies to create the effect you want.

For example, if your set the `OnAction` property to vbNullString.  This not only neuters the button, it also changes the button behavior during run time so that a single left click puts it into the caption editing mode.  It could be used for a novel, and highly unorthodox, quasi-clipboard.

Or you could go more mainstream, perhaps with @Storax's solution.

Or maybe add some flavor to it by briefly changing the backcolor when clicked.  The simple animation adds a nice touch, in fact, I prefer for that over an unclickable button.

You could jump the shark and turn all that clickyness into a mood improving anger reduction tool.  Or a cruel joke on the office intern.  Or a hilarious joke on your boss.

Or maybe you don't like the click so youou  throw a locked transparent text box over it and tweek the sheet protections to give the user sufficient freedom while prohibiting interaction with that text box.

But in the end, if the button isn't animated then it's just as useful as a static image.  So maybe you just want to use a picture instead of a button.

With so many choices, it's like the world is your oyster...

...So go find some pearls!

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. Unfortunately this didn't work. I also need to be able to disable it from another sub.

Comment: @JGoode Oh, I should have read that better... "Worksheet" button. Will update my answer.

Comment: It seems that is not possible, see one of the answers [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/officeversion_other-customize/excel-2010-enabledisable-buttons-via-vba/793de6e3-6c20-4706-876d-1421209aad98)